# Google map fill page remaining beneath header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header div appear above a Google map, but have the map fill all of the rest of the page content.

The trouble I have is that the page keeps scrolling and I don't want it to. It scrolls the same amount as the header height. I tried putting overflow: hidden but that doesn't work because although it no longer scrolls it also doesn't show the google logo and legal stuff that is required.

This is my html:

```
<body>
  <header>Title</header>
  <div id="appcontent">
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#appcontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
```

I've made a Fiddle of what I'm trying to do here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5LVQX/1/

Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using absolute positioning, like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/5LVQX/2/))

```
#map-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
header {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;    
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
}
```

See [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values).

Answer (score 1):

> overflow: hidden

on

> body

should also work.

Edit:

Will need

CSS

```
#appcontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Comment: this will hide some of the map the map area.

Comment: _calc_ is something interesting. Just need to be aware about browser support, otherwise lovely!

Comment: The first option conceals `40px` of the map and the second option only has support in more recent browser versions. Check out http://caniuse.com/calc. It's not nearly as universal as `position: absolute`.

Comment: Yah I know, was making the best out of my dumb answer.. it was either that or deleting it. Now it's at least half an answer..

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is, add this JS line:

```
$("#appcontent").height($(document.body).height() - $("header").height());
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5LVQX/3/

Comment: This question isn't tagged with [tag:javascript] or [tag:jquery].

Comment: Thanks for telling me, I never knew that! But as _jQuery_ is being used there, no harm in adding one more line there.

Comment: Apart from unnecessary scripting to handle a display concern. Additionally, the map won't resize with the window in this implementation. To fix that, you'd need to add _more_ script to handle `window.onresize`.