# responsive design with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I m trying to have a responsive page which has two buttons on the top and supposed to be centered. Under the buttons i added a google map which should cover the rest of the page. when i try the code bellow, the buttons are not centered and also not responsive. and somehow the map height is longer than the page so scrollbar shows up. And ideas where i m doing wrong ?

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 center-block">
                    <button >click me</button>
                    <button >click me</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="map_container">
            <div id="googleMap" class="map_canvas"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.map_container{

    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.map_container .map_canvas{

    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Giving `padding` a percentage uses the percentage of the parent's width, not the height. It's a quirk of `padding`.

Comment: Can you put up fiddle?

Comment: Check JKillian answer about [Container-fluid vs .container](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22263969/1151408). Why not putting map inside container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two part question/answer:

1. The `.center-block` class only sets `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;` thus the browser will render the "block" centred assuming that the width is know.  Works well with a `<img width="` tag, but an undefined-width `<div>` is not of a know width, so most browsers ignore the `margin:auto`.  There are two ways to fix this:

   a. Create a innner div with a fixed width, i.e. `<div style="width:200px">..buttons..</div>`

   b. *(HTML5 proponents will wince at this, but...)* The `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5 but still works in all the browsers I know of.  e.g. `<center>..buttons..</center>` - so if it works then why not.
2. Harder to answer because there are several things that cause misbehaviour and I don't know (from your example) what effect you're trying to produce:

   a. `.map_canvas{ height:100%; width:100%; }` - not sure why?  Width and Height with percentages use the ancestor object metrics, so w=100% will use the full width of the viewport (expected) and h=100% will use the **full height of the viewport**, meaning the total combined height of the map-container and the container+buttons above it.

   b. `.map_container{ height:0; }` - not sure why?  There should never be a reason for that - either `display:none` or `height: auto|length|initial|inherit`.

   c. `.map_container{ position:relative; }` -> `.map_canvas{ position:absolute; }` ???  Not sure what you're doing there?  Have a look at [#21022512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022512/google-map-fill-page-remaining-beneath-header#21022607) that has this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/5LVQX/2/) --- If that's it then remember to up-vote it.

**PS:** Try asking one question at a time - some StackExchange users may know the answer to one and not the other and then they may just not answer at all.  And.., use jsfiddle.com to create a reproduction of your issue.  The post a link to it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this purely using Bootstrap classes and little restructuring of HTML.

please check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnelsonin/u4yth8t4/).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >click me</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" >click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="map_container">
    <div id="googleMap" class="map_canvas"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googleMap');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </div>

</div>
```